# How to unhide Image Captions in Photoswipe for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, photoswipe

I'm using PhotoSwipe Gallery in my Wordpress theme and when I open the Slideshow, the Image Captions don't appear.

I'm trying to write a plugin for Wordpress which should fix this problem. As far as I know (thank God there is Google Chrome's Inspect Element function!!!) the div that I would need to change is the following:

```
<div class="ps-caption-content">&nbsp;</div>
```

If I insert something else than   between the div tags in Google Chrome's Inspector it becomes the Image's caption.

But I have no idea how to write a jQuery or javaScript function in order change the caption.

I googled and found the following suggestion for customizing PhotoSwipe Image captions, but it didn't work for me:

https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/src/examples/11-custom-captions.html

Does anyone have an idea how I could unhide/show the real captions of the images in the slideshow?

I added wrote a new Plugin for Wordpress and installed and activated. It contains a **js** folder with .js file called **custom_photoswipe_image_titles.js**.

Inside my plugin I have the following php code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: wpCasa Image Titles
Plugin URI: 
Description:  Adds titles above the listing gallery images
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Elshan Siradjov
Author URI: http://www.w3schools.com/
License: 
*/


/**
 * Load javascript and css Files
 *
 */



function image_titles_add_to_doc_head()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('photoswipe-style', 'http://www.siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/js/photoswipe/photoswipe.css');

    wp_register_script( 'klassmin', 'http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/js/photoswipe/klass.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'klassmin' );

    wp_register_script( 'code_photoswipe', 'http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/js/photoswipe/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'code_photoswipe' );



    wp_register_script( 'custom_js_photoswipe_image_titles', 'http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/plugins/wpcasa-image-titles/js/custom_photoswipe_image_titles.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js_photoswipe_image_titles' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'image_titles_add_to_doc_head' );
```

Inside the **custom_photoswipe_image_titles.js** file I tried the following jquery code in order to change the image caption:

```
$('div.ps-caption-content').html('Test Caption');
```

But it didn't work. The caption is still empty.

I also to tried to embed the jQuery code in a document ready function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)   
{   
    $('div.ps-caption-content').html("blabla");    
});
```

It didn't work either.

@vico: I found a piece of code inside **code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js**:

```
(function(e,c,a){

 a.registerNamespace("Code.PhotoSwipe.Toolbar");
 var b=e.Code.PhotoSwipe;

 b.Toolbar.CssClasses={
      toolbar:"ps-toolbar",
      toolbarContent:"ps-toolbar-content",
      toolbarTop:"ps-toolbar-top",
      caption:"ps-caption",
      captionBottom:"ps-caption-bottom",
      captionContent:"ps-caption-content",   // This is where ps-caption-content is set!
      close:"ps-toolbar-close",
      play:"ps-toolbar-play",
      previous:"ps-toolbar-previous",
      previousDisabled:"ps-toolbar-previous-disabled",
      next:"ps-toolbar-next",
      nextDisabled:"ps-toolbar-next-disabled"};
  .....
  ......
```

I also found this code inside **code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js**:

```
initialize:function(d,c){
var g;
this.settings=c;
this.cache=d;
this.isVisible=!1;
this.fadeOutHandler=this.onFadeOut.bind(this);
this.touchStartHandler=this.onTouchStart.bind(this);
this.touchMoveHandler=this.onTouchMove.bind(this);
this.clickHandler=this.onClick.bind(this);
g=b.Toolbar.CssClasses.toolbar;
this.settings.captionAndToolbarFlipPosition&&(g=g+" "+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.toolbarTop);
this.toolbarEl=a.DOM.createElement("div",{"class":g},this.settings.getToolbar());

a.DOM.setStyle(this.toolbarEl,{left:0,position:"absolute",overflow:"hidden",zIndex:this.settings.zIndex});
this.settings.target===e?a.DOM.appendToBody(this.toolbarEl):a.DOM.appendChild(this.toolbarEl,this.settings.target);

a.DOM.hide(this.toolbarEl);
this.closeEl=a.DOM.find("."+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.close,this.toolbarEl)[0];
this.settings.preventHide&&!a.isNothing(this.closeEl)&&a.DOM.hide(this.closeEl);
this.playEl=a.DOM.find("."+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.play,this.toolbarEl)[0];
this.settings.preventSlideshow&&!a.isNothing(this.playEl)&&a.DOM.hide(this.playEl);
this.nextEl=a.DOM.find("."+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.next,this.toolbarEl)[0];
this.previousEl=a.DOM.find("."+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.previous,this.toolbarEl)[0];
g=b.Toolbar.CssClasses.caption;this.settings.captionAndToolbarFlipPosition&&(g=g+" "+b.Toolbar.CssClasses.captionBottom);
this.captionEl=a.DOM.createElement("div",{"class":g},"");
a.DOM.setStyle(this.captionEl,{left:0,position:"absolute",overflow:"hidden",zIndex:this.settings.zIndex});
this.settings.target===e?a.DOM.appendToBody(this.captionEl):a.DOM.appendChild(this.captionEl,this.settings.target);
a.DOM.hide(this.captionEl);

this.captionContentEl=a.DOM.createElement("div",{"class":b.Toolbar.CssClasses.captionContent},"");    // This where captionContent is being set!!!

a.DOM.appendChild(this.captionContentEl,this.captionEl);
this.addEventHandlers()},
```

In the function above the following line seems to be setting the value for the ps-caption-content:

```
this.captionContentEl=a.DOM.createElement("div",{"class":b.Toolbar.CssClasses.captionContent},"");
```

Comment: can you give the full example of your code including your Image div slides as well? typically $('ps-caption-content').html('blabla'); will insert text but **WHAT and WHERE** is your text is the question atm.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion $('ps-caption-content').html('blabla'); but still it doesn't work. The caption area remains empty.

Comment: text search insdie one of those imported js files for "ps-caption-content", the above code doesn't work because it is executed on runtime page load event and this item might be created from one of those js file during that time or after

Comment: I tried the following code inside **custom_photoswipe_image_titles.js** :  `jQuery(document).ready(function($)  
{  
$('div.ps-caption-content').html("blabla");  

});`  It still doesn't work.

Comment: @vico: I found a piece of code inside **code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js**:

Answer (score 2):

That isn't the place to be changing it.

here is a fiddle of the actual code that outputs your DIV

```
 this.captionContentEl = a.DOM.createElement("div", {
                "class": b.Toolbar.CssClasses.captionContent
            }, "");
```

and here is a fiddle of your source code expanded

http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/js/photoswipe/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js

**http://jsfiddle.net/SjZWy/**

NOW you just have to find out where in the code produces your ACTUAL caption and then stick the caption var string into that div and your thing will work.

Comment: How can I use the jsfiddle? The HTML is missing, isn't it?

Comment: it is just the source code expanded into a easier to read format. where do you have on your page the display of your actual caption contents? just try putting contents into the "" (which is why your current divs are empty) you have to know where your wanted aka **Source** of your wanted caption so you can find it via elebyID then put the content inside there.

Comment: For example when you open http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/?property=unique-villa-with-private-beach and then scroll down to the **Gallery** section and click on 1 of the images (e.g. wpcasa-02) in the gallery, the slideshow will open. The current image in the slideshow should have a caption in the upper bar. In Google Chrome I can inspect the upper bar Element and it opens the  <div class="ps-caption-content">&nbsp;</div>. Now in Google Chrome I can just test it and insert something between the div tags and shows me the right caption.

Comment: Unfortunately the div doesn't have an id. I don't where the HTML gets generated. Probably in some .php file but I don't know how to find this piece of code. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: well looking at just the code (unless your plugin has a setting for this, it seems like alot of coding to add this additional caption. I think at this point you might as well try a new plugin for this. or look at the documentation for this plugin, if there is some setting you can play around with.. since adding that in through the code might not seem like a good solution.

Comment: I know, I started a new Wordpress Plugin already with a jQuery part. The problem is that I don't how to access the caption setting via jQuery and when it should be triggered. To which event should I hook it?